Recognizing when a $2\pi$-periodic function is a shifted sine
Consider a real analytic function $f(x)$ with a period of $2\pi.$ Let $t\in \operatorname{Range}(f(x))$, $$I(t)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log |t-f(x)|dx.$$ Prove that $I(t)$ is equal to a constant if and only if $f(x)=A\sin(n(x+B)+C)$ where $A,B,C\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}.$
A tool that may be needed is as follows.
[(Jensen's Formula): For $R>0$ and $f\in C^w,$ let $\{z_k\}=\{|z|<R \mid f(z)=0\},$ if $f(0)\neq 0$ and $f(z)\neq 0,~\forall |z|=R$ then it holds that
\begin{equation}\label{eq11}\log |f(0)|=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \log |\frac{|z_k|}{R}|+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log |f(Re^{i\theta})|d\theta.]\end{equation}

If there is a typo, click the "edit" button and fix it.

I’m voting to close this question because it’s homework.

This is not homework, in fact, it's a guess. I've been trying for a long time. I would be very grateful if you could provide some references or ideas.

Editorialising about the difficulty of your question does not belong in the title.  I have edited to a neutral title.  Feel free to change it to be more descriptive, but please do not restore the editorialising.

Thanks for the suggestion, I will write it more formally.@LSpice
